# Assigning Raw Data Into Bucket Categories Counts

Tags: excel

I have my raw data in Excel in the following format.

[image]

How can I turn assign them into bucket counts like
the resulting table I have?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in columns A:C and your report (with the blue headers) is in cells E1:H3, the following formulas will work.

Cell F2 `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<=5",B:B,"<"&$E3,B:B,">="&$E2)`

Cell G2 `=COUNTIFS($C:$C,"<=10",$C:$C,">5",$B:$B,"<"&$E3,$B:$B,">="&$E2)`

Cell H2 `=COUNTIFS($C:$C,">10",$B:$B,"<"&$E3,$B:$B,">="&$E2)`

Then copy these formulas down for their respective columns.

The only trick is to ensure that you have a long list of dates starting at the first of the month (i.e. you date for Jul-16 & Aug-16 is actually July 1st 2016 & August 1st 2016). To make the sample you have shown work, I have added Sep 1, 2016 just below Aug-16. I imagine you want to continue the dates going forward anyway therefore this formula will capture all dates as well as new additions going forward.

Note that I have hard coded your 5 & 10 day criteria into the formulas. I would suggest linking these to cells which you could alter at any time, thus changing one cell rather than altering every formula in each column.